# Unable to work on ImageMagick properly on Windows xampp

Tags: php, windows, apache, imagemagick

I read all the questions before posting this .
I am trying to install ImageMagick on my local system Windows 7.It gets installed without But when i try using it to crop images I get NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat .
I am running Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

This is what i did

- I installed ImageMagick ImageMagick-6.8.9-8-Q16-x86-dll.exe (I tried 6.8.1 and 6.7 also)
- I got the dll from http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows TS for PHP 5.4
- Updated php.ini
- The server started with out problem .
- I checked via cmd the ImageMagick is working fine.
- phpinfo() ImageMagick number of supported formats:   0

I tried many DLL's but none is working i need a solution to this .

Also phpinfo keeps on showing ImageMagick version:ImageMagick 6.8.8-4 Q16 x86 2014-01-29 even when i uninstalled it / updated it .

identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86 2014-08-26 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo png ps rsv
g tiff webp xml zlib

I am trying to open Jpg.

Comment: Try `identify -version` to see the version and installed delegates. Also, tell us what type of file you could not open please.

Answer (score 7):

ImageMagick inside php is a really different from the standalone cmd version.

So, you need not only the `php_imagic.dll` connected to your `php.ini`.
But also the  `CORE_RL_*_.dll` files in the Apache `bin` directory.
This will enable the readers.
Now you need the ENcoders. These are obtained from the standalone installation and located in `[ImageMagick install dir]\modules\coders`. Copy them to Apache's `bin` directory as well.

Now check the `phpinfo();`

The downside of this is that you need to match dll's from Standalone version to the one that is Compiled in the php-extension.

Comment: Thank you, copying the `\modules\coders` files in the Apache `bin` directory solved it for me.

Comment: thankyou! not a single guide or answer before this mentioned that you should copy the \modules\coders as well !